# OTRS fetch info from url

Tags: otrs

I've OTRS 5 working fine . I need to retrieve information from web 
for example I received emails from support team they put in the subject (customer ID) I need to put in the body message of the Ticket the customer information based on Customer ID which will fetch it from another local system through Url  e.x "skldfj.com/dslkde.php?id=23487893"

for example I received ticket in subject: customer 23487893 have issue
 in body need to be something like

### hello team this customer (ID 23487893) have issue

customer info (fetch it from skldfj.com/dslkde.php?id=23487893)

---

name
 telephone and more